# Wordpress Plugin Basepath Confusion

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I am working on a WP plugin for an application that runs within a wordpress page with a short code.  The plugin appears to be running ok but in the console I see the following errors:

```
https://www.MyWebsiteRoot.zzz/WPFolder/MyPluginFolder/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.11.3 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
https://www.MyWebsiteRoot.zzz/WPFolder/MyPluginFolder/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/datepicker.min.js?ver=1.11.4 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
https://www.MyWebsiteRoot.zzz/WPFolder/MyPluginFolder/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.2.1 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
https://www.MyWebsiteRoot.zzz/WPFolder/MyPluginFolder/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/mouse.min.js?ver=1.11.4 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
https://www.MyWebsiteRoot.zzz/WPFolder/MyPluginFolder/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/core.min.js?ver=1.11.4 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
https://www.MyWebsiteRoot.zzz/WPFolder/MyPluginFolder/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/widget.min.js?ver=1.11.4 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
https://www.MyWebsiteRoot.zzz/WPFolder/MyPluginFolder/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/button.min.js?ver=1.11.4 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
https://www.MyWebsiteRoot.zzz/WPFolder/MyPluginFolder/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/slider.min.js?ver=1.11.4 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
https://www.MyWebsiteRoot.zzz/WPFolder/MyPluginFolderjs/wp-emoji-release.min.js?ver=4.4.1 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
https://www.MyWebsiteRoot.zzz/WPFolder/MyPluginFolder/wp-includes/js/wp-embed.min.js?ver=4.4.1 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
https://www.MyWebsiteRoot.zzz/WPFolder/MyPluginFolder/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/spinner.min.js?ver=1.11.4 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
tinynav.js?ver=4.4.1:91 Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).tinyNav is not a function
```

It appears that the base path gets confused at some point.  MyPluginFolder should not be included in the string.  I am not sure where this is initiated.  I  am not sure how to correct it.  I am assuming it is initiated by my plugin because it is using MyPluginFolder as the base path. I am looking for tips on how to troubleshoot and correct this.

This is my code for the path in the plugin:

```
/** Base Plugin Path */
define('EAWP_BASEPATH', __DIR__); 

/** Supported Versions */
define('EAWP_MIN_VERSION', '1.0');
define('EAWP_MAX_VERSION', '1.0');

/** Setup Autoloader */
require EAWP_BASEPATH . '/core/Autoload.php'; 
$loader = new EAWP\Core\Autoload; 
$loader->register();
$loader->addNamespace('EAWP\Core', EAWP_BASEPATH . '/core');
$loader->addNamespace('EAWP\Core\Interfaces', EAWP_BASEPATH . '/core/interfaces');
$loader->addNamespace('EAWP\Core\Exceptions', EAWP_BASEPATH . '/core/exceptions');
$loader->addNamespace('EAWP\Core\ValueObjects', EAWP_BASEPATH . '/core/value-objects');
$loader->addNamespace('EAWP\Libraries', EAWP_BASEPATH . '/libraries'); 

/** Initialize Plugin */
global $wpdb; 
$route = new EAWP\Core\Route(); 
$plugin = new EAWP\Core\Plugin($wpdb, $route);
$plugin->initialize();

if(!function_exists('wp_get_current_user')) {
    include(ABSPATH . "wp-includes/pluggable.php"); 
}
```

Comment: would you mind adding your code in you post?

Comment: Also we have no idea where these assets would be if they aren't in your plugin directory

Comment: Thank you, I have added some code from my plug in.  I am thinking it starts here.

Comment: @Craig how did you enqueue your javascripts?

Comment: Directory structure sure looks weird for wordpress plugin. Norm would be for it to be in `wp-content/plugins/YourPlugin`. And you would never put anything in `wp-includes` or end up with update nightmares.

Comment: The plugin is in `wp-content/plugins/`. I am not seeing how anything I have in my plugin results in what I am getting in errors however. The wp-includes/pluggable.php is a WP file.